# Hide and Show using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a easy hide and show script that is separated from the HTML-code. But I can't get it to work. Anyone?
HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="area">
            <h1>JavaScript</h1>
            <button class="button">Click!</button>
            <p class="text">Adöfkljg ldjfögj jsdflkgjh kjddflkgjh dfgkjdöjg </p>
            <button class="button">Click!!</button>
            <p class="text">dfghödifgjöoeirugeöori dijfoidj oidoi odi!</p>
        </div>
        <script src="visa.js"></script>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
var butt = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

window.onload = start();
function start(){
    for (i=0; i<text.length; i++){
        text[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    };

};

butt[i].onclick = function (){
        if (text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
            text[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{
            text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"
        };

    };
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZskCk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. `if (text[i].style.visibility = "hidden")` is always true, it should be:

   `if (text[i].style.visibility == "hidden")`
2. The following code:

   ```
   butt[i].onclick = function (){
     if (text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
       text[i].style.visibility = "visible";
     } else {
       text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"
     };
   };
   ```

was out of the `for` loop, so `i` was not defined, and also when you go into the function (in the future with a click) `i` will not be defined. So, I moved the event listener to the button declaration.

I've fixed the problems and [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZskCk/1/)

basically, you can take a look and compare the new code with your original.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but there still is some things that I don't understand. Why and how is console.log solving this problem?

Comment: don't mind the console.log, it was just a test I made. you can remove it.

Comment: The OP is posing a question about a "script that is separated from the HTML-code". Doing `<button class="button" onclick="toggle(0);">` is an awful mix of JS and HTML and should be avoided.

Comment: You are right, but he doesn't use jQuery, and nor the question is tagged as jQuery. Without it, this way is not so "awful"

Comment: Delal, I hope my solution was helpful to see where you were wrong. I do agree with @lukaszfiszer that you should learn jQuery, it's a nice and clean framework for DOM manipulations and more.

Comment: @ShayElkayam you can still write separated code in plain Javascript by using `element.addEventListener` method. I dont say that plain JS is "awful", but `onclick="toggle(0);` is definitely a bad practice and should be avoided

Comment: I agree. it can also be written as obj.onclick = function(){}; Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're beginning coding in Javascript and HTML. In this case, I'd recommend you to have a look at jQuery as a solid framework for DOM manipulation. To answer your question using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.text').hide();    
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.text').toggle()
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLju5/1/